# Print out a list of items with Django

Tags: python, json, django

I'm developing a Django project and i'm trying to solve an issue.

My main scope is getting a JSON file through a url and print out the data into a table(HTML).

To be more clearly, i got an Object like referred below and every record i would like to printed into my table.

```
{
"myData": [{
            "name": "John",
            "surname": "Williams",
            "birthday": "05/12/1997",
        }, {
            "name": "John",
            "surname": "Williams",
            "birthday": "05/12/1997",
        },]}


<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
          <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Birth Day</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              {% for myData in range(20) %}
                <tr>
                    <td> {{ myData.name }} </td>
                    <td> {{ myData.surname }} </td>
                    <td> {{ myData.birthday }} </td>
                </tr>
              {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

I find it as a very common implementation but still i can't find a solution. Also when i'm trying to run the code below inside my `views.py` file everything works great but If i'm trying to send data into an `.html` file i got multiple errors.

```
for i in range(5):
    print name[i]
```

The first one when i wrote

```
{% for x in range(20) %}
```

I got this error :

> Could not parse the remainder: '(20)' from 'range(20)'

Then I'm trying to pass range(20) as a variable from views.py file so i change the object line of code as

```
Object = {'name': name, .... , 'range': range(20)}
```

This time i was lucky with the remainder error but still unlucky with my data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a cycle of this kind {%for element in myData%} and in table you will  write  {{ element.name }} , etc.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i get an blank cell nothing changes.

Comment: Of course, firstly i store data in lists  

`for x in range(len(data)):
    name.append(data['myData'][x]['name'])
    surname.append(data['myData'][x]['surname'])
    birthday.append(data['myData'][x]['birthday'])`

Then I send them into my template page :

`def home(request):
    Object = {'name': name, 'surname': surname ....etc }
    return render(request , 'basic.html', context=Object)
`

Comment: Your object so strange) 
myData = [] 
for x in data['myData']: 
 tmp = {} 
 tmp['name'] = x['name'] 
 tmp['surname'] = x['surname'] 
 tmp['birtday'] = x['birthday'] 
 myData.append(tmp) 
And then in render 
context={'myData': myData} 
It's should work. 
If not then write me, 
I will correct it. Sorry for waiting:) P.S. tmp = {} to myData.append in cycle.

Comment: First of all you are so helpful. I used your implementation but when i'm trying to display the data i get an empty cell. The Object is correct 100% i checked it.

Comment: I looked at my old django project, my return was like return render(request, 'main/article.html', {'article': article}). And I forgot to ask you. Is your table enclosed in a block content?

Comment: Yeap, I used this code to display `{% for i in myData %} {{ i.name }} {% endfor %}`. 

Finally i solved it. Thanks for your help !